# Removing index.php from Laravel in sub directory Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I am attempting to run two codebases under the same domain, a static vue-cli site and a Laravel backend api.

The static site will be used for the frontend, and this will query the laravel codebase. I am having trouble removing index.php from my laravel urls.

My filesystem is as follows;

```
/var/www/site/frontend/dist/index.html <-- static homepage
                           /another.html <-- another static page
/var/www/site/backend/api/index.php <-- api access
```

Requests to my api will look something like

```
/api <-- laravel landing page, only for debugging
/api/autocomplete/artist/{artistName}
/api/autocomplete/artist/{artistName}/album/{albumTitle}
```

I think i am close but not quite there, the best I have had is the l
Laravel landing page, but whenever i add route parameters I get a 404, below is my config;

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/site/frontend/dist;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    # Make index.php in /api url unnecessary
    location /api {
      alias /var/www/site/backend/api;

      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$is_args$args;

     location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
     }

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `^~` modifier, otherwise your other `location ~ \.php$` block takes precedence with the wrong document root. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

You do not need to use `alias` as the last part of the document root matches the location - which simplifies things as `alias` and `try_files` has [issues](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) when used together.

The last element of the `try_files` statement should be a URI, which needs to include the location prefix. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

For example:

```
location ^~ /api {
    root /var/www/site/backend;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php?r=$is_args$args;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I wasn't even close was I, Thank you very much for this.